# How to get the sum of transaction amount happened in one date?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, plsql, oracle11g

I am trying to write a query that will give me transaction amount sum happened in one date. The problem is , when I added column date in my query, I get individual values not their sum. The requirement for this query is to have one entry for each merchant but i am getting multiple rows for one merchant.

```
SELECT SUBSTR(m.MERCHANTLASTNAME, 1, 36) Name1,                 

                                     m.MERCHANTBANKBSB MerchantAccbsb,                 

                                     m.MERCHANTBANKACCNR Merchant_act,                 

                                     m.MERCHANTID merchantid, 

                                     t.transactiondate date1,
                                     sum(t.TRANSACTIONAMOUNT) as total            

            FROM fss_merchant m 
            JOIN fss_terminal term 
            ON m.MERCHANTID = term.MERCHANTID                        
            JOIN FSS_DAILY_TRANSACTION t 
            ON term.TERMINALID = t.TERMINALID 
            group by t.transactiondate, SUBSTR(m.MERCHANTLASTNAME, 1, 36), m.MERCHANTID, m.MERCHANTBANKBSB, m.MERCHANTBANKACCNR, 
    m.MERCHANTLASTNAME
```

Output of my query:
[image: here]

I want to get one entry per each merchant with the sum of transaction amount in one day, not multiple rows of transaction in that day.

Comment: m.MERCHANTBANKBSB, m.MERCHANTBANKACCNR, m.MERCHANTID have unique values for every merchant as you can see in the output of my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the total amount in different inner query with the truncated date and join it with FSS_MERCHANT table so that issues described by @SatishSK and @mangusta is taken care.

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTR(M.MERCHANTLASTNAME, 1, 36) NAME1,
    M.MERCHANTBANKBSB        MERCHANTACCBSB,
    M.MERCHANTBANKACCNR      MERCHANT_ACT,
    M.MERCHANTID             MERCHANTID,
    M_DATA.TRANSACTIONDATE   DATE1,
    M_DATA.TOTAL             AS TOTAL
FROM
    FSS_MERCHANT M
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            TERM.MERCHANTID   MERCHANTID,
            TRUNC(T.TRANSACTIONDATE) TRANSACTIONDATE,
            SUM(T.TRANSACTIONAMOUNT) AS TOTAL
        FROM
            FSS_TERMINAL TERM
            JOIN FSS_DAILY_TRANSACTION T ON TERM.TERMINALID = T.TERMINALID
        GROUP BY
            TERM.MERCHANTID,
            TRUNC(T.TRANSACTIONDATE)
    ) M_DATA ON ( M.MERCHANTID = M_DATA.MERCHANTID );
```

Good luck!!

Answer (score 0):

t.transactiondate column might contain date+time values. Use TRUNC(t.transactiondate) where you are using just t.transactiondate. You will get sum(transaction amount) "Date-wise" for each merchant.

OR

Filter out rows based on "Date" value in WHERE clause to retrieve data pertaining to a specific date.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the reason is that you have included both `m.MERCHANTLASTNAME` and `SUBSTR(m.MERCHANTLASTNAME,1,36)` into the `group by` clause.

In case if there are entries with same `SUBSTR(m.MERCHANTLASTNAME,1,36)` but different `m.MERCHANTLASTNAME`, this is going to yield duplicates. You need to remove `m.MERCHANTLASTNAME` from `group by` clause

Comment: Tried what you said and still getting the same issue. multiple values for same merchant on same date. :(

Comment: so you tried `group by t.transactiondate, SUBSTR(m.MERCHANTLASTNAME,1,36), m.MERCHANTID, m.MERCHANTBANKBSB, m.MERCANTBANKACCNR` and you still get duplicates?

Comment: possibly one (or more) out of the 4 columns (`t.transactiondate`, `m.MERCHANTID`, `m.MERCHANTBANKBSB`, `m.MERCANTBANKACCNR`) contain space or tab character. use `trunc()` on all those columns one by one and check if duplicates occur

Comment: Still getting the same issue.

Comment: is this what you tried? `group by trunc(t.transactiondate), SUBSTR(m.MERCHANTLASTNAME,1,36), trunc(m.MERCHANTID), trunc(m.MERCHANTBANKBSB), trunc(m.MERCHANTBANKACCNR)`

Comment: i tried what you have suggested and its giving me an error. ""M"."MERCANTBANKACCNR": invalid identifier"

Comment: that's my misprint, i've edited `group by` part above